# Cannot open games or video on ipad

Tags: games

I updated some games on my ipad mini, in addition to downloading several new ones. Now every time I try to play anything, nothing works. I click on a game, and it will not open. The same is true for all the videos. What do I need to do?

Comment: Did you restart your iPad already? How much memory does your iPad have, how much is still available?

Answer (score 1):

Force restart your iPad:

> You should force restart your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch as a last resort, and only if it's not responding. To force restart your device, press and hold both the Sleep/Wake and Home button for at least 10 seconds, until you see the Apple logo.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201559